# Using string functions in Cloudformation for Lambda Code

Tags: string, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I have a cloudformation snippet that looks roughly like this:

```
"LambdaScale": {
  "Type": "AWS::Lambda::Function",
  "Properties": {
    ...
    "Code": {
      "S3Bucket": {
        {
          "Ref": "LambdaBucket"
        }
      },
      "S3Key": {
        "Fn::Join": [
          "/",
          [
            { 
              "Ref": "LambdaDirectoryKey"
            },
            "some_func.zip"
          ]
        ]
      }
    },
 ...
 }
```

But when I try to run this, I get the following error:

> An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the CreateStack
>   operation: Template format error:
>   [/Resources/LambdaScale/Type/Code/S3Bucket] map keys must be strings;
>   received a map instead

Reading this, it makes me think that the S3Bucket and S3Key properties are expecting a string literal, and do not support the string manipulation functions.  Can this really be true?  If so, that is a huge barrier for deploying these templates on different environments.

Is there perhaps a workaround I have not considered?  Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have:

```
  "S3Bucket": {
    {
      "Ref": "LambdaBucket"
    }
  },
```

it should probably be:

```
  "S3Bucket": {
      "Ref": "LambdaBucket"
  },
```